# Adobe CQ | Is there any way to customize multifield component to have multiple images via drag and drop?

Tags: extjs, aem

I have trying to develop a component where in one can drag as many image as he want in a single dialog box under one tab. I tried to edit the multifield component but with no success.
Is there any way to customize multifield component to have multiple images via drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

The smartimage xtype is meant to be on it's own TabPanel. http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.SmartImage  Since it wants to fill the whole panel you will have display issues.

I've seen lots of issues when trying to add the smartimage widget to a multifield.  One of the other main problems is the smartimage drag and drop events won't fire.  The multifield would need to account for every type of component and all the different events each could fire.  It doesn't handle them well at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2013/12/aem-cq-56-adding-images-in-multifield.html it has necessary extension logic to add images in multifield